# Set the body width to 100% of document's

Tags: html, css

So i have:

```
    <body style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:2000px;">
            1
        </div>
    <body>
```

Is there any way to make body width to be 100% of document (including "scrolling space") instead of 100% of inner window width in this case?
I mean i need the result as if i applied "width:2000px;" to the body, but without knowing this number.

I know, that it will take one line of code in js and still i wonder, if i can do this with pure css.

To clarify: 
When i write "width:100%;" i expect, that body width will stretch up to 2000px (to include that absolutely positioned div), but it stretches only to 1024px (browser window width).

Comment: Do you want to hide the scroll or have it outside the browser width? Both horizontal and vertical (if I understand your question right)

Comment: `width:100%` should work. I think you may want to try `overflow:hidden` on the body as well.

Comment: I thought i described it as simple as i could... I need the body to FILL all the space to the right. Now it's width is only as big as my browser window width (1024px) then goes white space.

Comment: Why do you make your `div` `left: 2000px;` ?

Comment: Because i tried to simplify a question. Position will be somehow defined and is needed to be absolute, not relative. P.S.: I need scrollbars, so i don't need overflow:hidden.

Comment: You want the body to expand to it's child's width? In this case being 2000px?

Comment: Can you post a JSFliddle document? Thanks..

Comment: It works as expected : http://jsbin.com/eqohes/1/

Comment: @Brewal does not work as expected. Put a `border: 1px solid black` on `<body>` and see that it is not stretched.

Comment: @Joe Frambach Thank you. That's what i'm talking about. The actual width. (I have edited the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logical puzzle with this layout.

```
<body style="background:red;width:100%;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:2000px;">
       1
    </div>
<body>
```

Because the inner `div` is positioned absolutely, it is out of the document flow, and therefore, the parent block container, `<body>`, cannot compute a width based on the absolutely positioned child element.

By assigning a percentage width of 100% to `<body>`, the width is actually being computed based on the width of the root element, in this case, `<html>`, which may in turn, inherit its height from the viewport.

**This effect cannot be achieved by CSS alone.**

If you need the inner div to be absolutely positioned, then you will need some JavaScript/jQuery functionality to determine the width of `<body>` based on some custom rules that you want to specify.

Comment: I told that i know how to solve that with js. So... no "hacks" or smth for pure css?

Comment: To be clear, the viewport is not the same as the root element; the root element box exists as a child of the viewport box. When you abspos an element that has no positioned ancestors, then it is always anchored to the viewport.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you for the point, I have corrected my answer accordingly to reflect the viewport -> html -> body tree structure.

Comment: No solution for me, still thank you for your clarification of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `position: absolute` what you can do is wrapping your `div` inside another one like this:

```
<body style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;">
    <div style="width:2000px;">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:2000px;">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

because when you make any element absolute is not belongs to is parent anymore and it becomes separate element in document (in document flow). If this answer is not what you want, tell me what you want exactly to do (what is your design decision) then I can give you alternative designs to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The width property doesn't have anything to do with the objects' child elements. Additionally, by absolute positioning that element, it actually causes the parent to COMPLETELY ignore any size parameters of that particular child element. But even with a relatively positioned object with an offset, only the initial position of the element would have an impact on its parent and not the offset location of it.

Setting width to 100% will cause it to fill 100% of its parent container, in this case the `<html>` element. And by explicitly stating a width, even if you had a large amount of unwrapped content inside that container, your width would actually be locked at 100% (or the width of the browser window) regardless of said child content.

You could TRY and set the width to 200%, which would cause it stretch to the right beyond its parent container. But this width would not be driven by the absolute positioned child element, and may not be responsive enough for your needs.

As was already stated above, there is no pure CSS solution for what you're trying to do and you'll need to use at least some javascript to accomplish what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish.